# Pytorch Forecasting: Loading a custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to load a custom dataset to PyTorch Forecasting by modifying the example given in [this Github repository](https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting/blob/master/docs/source/tutorials/building.ipynb). However I'm stuck at instantiating the `TimeSeriesDataSet`. The relevant parts of the code are as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df.shape) # (300, 8)

# Divide the timestamps so that they are incremented by one each row.
df["unix"] = df["unix"].apply(lambda n: int(n / 86400))

# Set "unix" as the index
#df = df.set_index("unix")

# Add *integer* indices.
df["index"] = np.arange(300)
df = df.set_index("index")

# Add group column.
df["group"] = np.repeat(np.arange(30), 10)

from pytorch_forecasting import TimeSeriesDataSet

target = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

# Create the dataset from the pandas dataframe
dataset = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    df,
    group_ids                  = ["group"],
    target                     = target,
    time_idx                   = "unix",
    min_encoder_length         = 50,
    max_encoder_length         = 50,
    min_prediction_length      = 20,
    max_prediction_length      = 20,
    time_varying_unknown_reals = target,
    allow_missing_timesteps    = True
)
```

And the error message plus traceback:

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/torch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_forecasting/data/timeseries.py:1241: UserWarning: Min encoder length and/or min_prediction_idx and/or min prediction length and/or lags are too large for 30 series/groups which therefore are not present in the dataset index. This means no predictions can be made for those series. First 10 removed groups: [{'__group_id__group': 0}, {'__group_id__group': 1}, {'__group_id__group': 2}, {'__group_id__group': 3}, {'__group_id__group': 4}, {'__group_id__group': 5}, {'__group_id__group': 6}, {'__group_id__group': 7}, {'__group_id__group': 8}, {'__group_id__group': 9}]
  warnings.warn(

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_822/3402560775.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # create the dataset from the pandas dataframe
----> 6 dataset = TimeSeriesDataSet(
      7     df,
      8     group_ids                  = ["group"],

~/.virtualenvs/torch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_forecasting/data/timeseries.py in __init__(self, data, time_idx, target, group_ids, weight, max_encoder_length, min_encoder_length, min_prediction_idx, min_prediction_length, max_prediction_length, static_categoricals, static_reals, time_varying_known_categoricals, time_varying_known_reals, time_varying_unknown_categoricals, time_varying_unknown_reals, variable_groups, constant_fill_strategy, allow_missing_timesteps, lags, add_relative_time_idx, add_target_scales, add_encoder_length, target_normalizer, categorical_encoders, scalers, randomize_length, predict_mode)
    437 
    438         # create index
--> 439         self.index = self._construct_index(data, predict_mode=predict_mode)
    440 
    441         # convert to torch tensor for high performance data loading later

~/.virtualenvs/torch/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_forecasting/data/timeseries.py in _construct_index(self, data, predict_mode)
   1247                 UserWarning,
   1248             )
-> 1249         assert (
   1250             len(df_index) > 0
   1251         ), "filters should not remove entries all entries - check encoder/decoder lengths and lags"

AssertionError: filters should not remove entries all entries - check encoder/decoder lengths and lags
```

I have tried tweaking the initializer arguments without success. The file `timeseries.py` can be found in the same Github repository, [here](https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting/blob/master/pytorch_forecasting/data/timeseries.py#L1246).

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, I guess it might happen because not all of your time series have a minimum length (`min_prediction_length` + `min_encoder_length`).

In your case, each time series should at least have a length of 70.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).